# Pygame local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a rectangle to run using keys but I take an error on line 34:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

I can't fix that. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

fps = 30
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
w = 640
h = 420
blue = (0, 0, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
x = w / 3
y = 350
boxa = 20
movex = 0


def drawwindow():
    global screen
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
    screen.fill(blue)


def drawbox(box):
    if box.right > (w - boxa):
        box.right = (w - boxa)
    if box.left < 0:
        box.left = 0
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, box)


def main():
    drawwindow()
    box1 = pygame.Rect(x, y, boxa, boxa)
    drawbox(box1)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = +4
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = -4
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    movex = 0
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    movex = 0
        x += movex
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsclock.tick(fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `x` is in the global scope.  Therefore, in order to modify its value inside the function `main`, you need to declare it as being global with [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

```
def main():
    global x
    ...
        x += movex
```

Note that you only need to do this if you *modify* a global.  Accessing their values works just fine.